# I installed termux using the emulator bluestacks i'm having trouble installing git as it throws this this error "unable to locate package git"

Tags: git, android-emulator, termux, bluestacks, termux-linux

I am trying to install Git on Termux but I keep getting the error "unable to locate package git" when I run the command "pkg install git". I have tried updating the package list with "pkg update" and then running the install command again, but I still get the same error.

I have also tried installing other packages and they work fine, so I don't think it's a problem with my internet connection or Termux itself.

What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.[the actual error that is being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym3jd.jpg)

My expectation was to successfully install Git on Termux so that i can use it for version control in our projects.

Answer (score 0):

1.Update the package lists:

```
pkg update
```

2.Ensure you have the necessary repositories enabled. Termux uses the official Android repositories by default, but you can add additional repositories to expand the available packages or you can Change it by *termux-change-repo*. To add the necessary repositories, run the following commands:

```
pkg install curl
curl -LO https://its-pointless.github.io/setup-pointless-repo.sh
bash setup-pointless-repo.sh
```

3.After adding the additional repositories, update the package lists again:

```
pkg update
```

4.Finally, install Git:

```
pkg install git
```

By adding the "pointless" repository, you should be able to find and install Git successfully. If you still encounter any issues, please let me know, and I'll be glad to assist you further.